# General programming, add two arrays vertically

Tags: arrays

I know how to concatenate two arrays, but that's not exactly what I want to do here.
Say I have these two arrays;

```
a = [1 2 3 0 5 0 7]
b = [1 0 3 0 0 6 0]
```

I want to combine these into a new array so that the value would be

```
c = [1 2 3 0 4 6 7]
```

Basically if the two numbers are the same, then it will be that number. If there is a number and a zero I want it to be that number. If there are two zeros, I want it to be zero.

I really do appreciate any help. Thank you.
An answer in a general programming language is preferred, but a post in any coding language will work.

Comment: This is simple iteration, comparison, and assignment.  Where are you having difficulty?

Comment: If you are learning to program, then I understand you may be finding it hard, but just asking for an answer does not help, and wastes our time. Show us what you have tried first.

Comment: In your c array, you must mean 1 2 3 0 5 6 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `a.length` == `b.length`:

In Java:

```
int[] c = new int[a.length];
for(int i=0; i < c.length; i++){
  if(a[i] > 0){
    c[i] = a[i];
  }else{
    c[i] = b[i];
  }
}
```

This is just a code sample that doesn't adequately account for a case where you might have 2 non-zero values that aren't the same.  Handling this will require further requirements, and is an exercise to be left to the reader.